# Arranging string using collation algorithm(unicode)

Tags: string, sorting, unicode, collation

How exactly unicode collation algorithm works? What is normalization step? No link seems to have a proper explanation regarding this.

Given two English alphabet strings to compare using the unicode algorithm, will they be in English dictionary order or some thing else?

Nothing seems to make sense in the following link for me

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/tr10-28.html#Main_Algorithm

Comment: Unicode Normalization is explicitly linked where it's mentioned: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/. Maybe you should start reading the basics of how Unicode works before getting to rather advanced topics; it may make more sense that way. Also, usually the runtime library of your language implements this algorithm, e.g. in C# you can just compare strings, possibly by stating an explicit culture to compare them in, which uses the algorithm. Very few people actually need to *implement* it themselves.

Comment: Did you read the whole article twice? What parts do you understand? What parts don’t you understand? I doubt that you understand “nothing”.